# Array de-aggregation with repetition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'd like to de-aggregate a mongo collection that has one record, with a single large, large list inside, to instead be represented as many records in another collection.  For the variables in the record that are not contained in the long array, this will mean repeating the top levels, above the arary, into each new record as it's copied to the new collection.

What I have is this:

```
> db.current.showOne()
{"name" : "thing",
"othervar" : 1,
"longcollection" : [
                    {"first": 1,
                     "second":2},
                    {"first": 3,
                     "second":4},
                    {"first": 5,
                     "second":6},
                    ... etc...
                    {"first": 10000,
                     "second":10001}
                    ]
}
```

What I would like is this:

```
> db.new.find().limit(5000).pretty()
{"name" : "thing",
"othervar" : 1,
"longcollection" :
                    {"first": 1,
                     "second":2}
},
{"name" : "thing",
"othervar" : 1,
"longcollection" :
                    {"first": 3,
                     "second":4}
},
{"name" : "thing",
"othervar" : 1,
"longcollection" :
                    {"first": 5,
                     "second":6}
},

{"name" : "thing",
"othervar" : 1,
"longcollection" :
                    {"first": 7,
                     "second":8}
}
```

..etc.

The information unique to each record is in the "longcollection" variable, which is now a dictionary, rather than an array.  The other information, on the same level as "longcollection", rather than inside it, is repeated for all new records.

I think this is kind of an unwrap, or unwind.  What is the syntax combination of copyTo() and unwrap/aggregation that would get me here?  I'm still kind of new on the javascript and aggregation sides of mongodb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/)

For your example above you can use:

```
db.current.aggregate({$unwind: "$longcollection"})
```

This will give you a result like this:

```
{
    result: : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId(...),
            "name": xxxx,
            "othervar": yyyyy,
            "longcollection" : {
                "first": 1, 
                "second":2
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId(...),
            "name": yyyy,
            "othervar": zzzz,
            "longcollection" : {
                "first": 3, 
                "second":4
            }
        }],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

---

To stop the duplicate _id message seen in the comment you should be able to use:

```
db.current.aggregate({$project : {_id: 0, name: 1, othervar: 1, longcollection: 1}}, {$unwind: "$longcollection"})
```

Comment: So, completing my example, I'm having trouble putting this into a new collection: `db.current.aggregate({$unwind: "$longcollection"}).result.forEach(function(x){
db.new.insert(x)})`  gives `E11000 duplicate key error index: db.new.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('51f09dd26f7320383b33ca83') }`

Comment: adding `delete x._id` before the insert statement seems to work.

Comment: Yes, taking the _id field with you means that you would get duplicate _ids when trying to insert. You could make it so the _id field doesn't come in to the $unwind by using [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/) to exclude it from the collection of data being unwound